# Wordcount Hadoop pipes C++ Running issue

Tags: c++, hadoop, mapreduce, pipe

I am trying to run the example of wordcount in C++ like this [link](http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_2.2_--_Running_C++_Programs_on_Hadoop) that describes the way to run the WordCount program in C++.

So I have this code in the file **wordcount.cpp**:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

#include  "stdint.h"  // <--- to prevent uint64_t errors! 

#include "Pipes.hh"
#include "TemplateFactory.hh"
#include "StringUtils.hh"

using namespace std;

class WordCountMapper : public HadoopPipes::Mapper {
public:
  // constructor: does nothing
  WordCountMapper( HadoopPipes::TaskContext& context ) {
  }

  // map function: receives a line, outputs (word,"1")
  // to reducer.
  void map( HadoopPipes::MapContext& context ) {
    //--- get line of text ---
    string line = context.getInputValue();

    //--- split it into words ---
    vector< string > words = HadoopUtils::splitString( line, " " );

    //--- emit each word tuple (word, "1" ) ---
    for ( unsigned int i=0; i < words.size(); i++ ) {
      context.emit( words[i], HadoopUtils::toString( 1 ) );
    }
  }
};

class WordCountReducer : public HadoopPipes::Reducer {
public:
  // constructor: does nothing
  WordCountReducer(HadoopPipes::TaskContext& context) {
  }

  // reduce function
  void reduce( HadoopPipes::ReduceContext& context ) {
    int count = 0;

    //--- get all tuples with the same key, and count their numbers ---
    while ( context.nextValue() ) {
      count += HadoopUtils::toInt( context.getInputValue() );
    }

    //--- emit (word, count) ---
    context.emit(context.getInputKey(), HadoopUtils::toString( count ));
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  return HadoopPipes::runTask(HadoopPipes::TemplateFactory<WordCountMapper,WordCountReducer>() );
}
```

I have this **Makefile**:

```
CC = g++
HADOOP_INSTALL = /home/hduser/Scrivania/hadoop-1.2.1
PLATFORM = Linux-amd64-64
CPPFLAGS = -m64 -I$(HADOOP_INSTALL)/c++/$(PLATFORM)/include/hadoop/

wordcount: wordcount.cpp 
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -Wall -lssl -lcrypto -L$(HADOOP_INSTALL)/c++/$(PLATFORM)/lib -lhadooppipes -lhadooputils -lpthread -g -O2 -o $@
```

The compilation works fine, but when I try to run my program as follow:

```
$ hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop pipes -D hadoop.pipes.java.recordreader=true \
-D hadoop.pipes.java.recordwriter=true -input input -output output -program wordcount
```

I have this result:

```
INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 4
INFO filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Creating filewordcount in /tmp/hadoop-hduser/mapred/local/archive/8648114132384070327_893673541_1470671038-work--6818354830621303575 with rwxr-xr-x
INFO filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Cached wordcount as /tmp/hadoop-hduser/mapred/local/archive/8648114132384070327_893673541_1470671038/filewordcount
INFO filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Cached wordcount as /tmp/hadoop-hduser/mapred/local/archive/8648114132384070327_893673541_1470671038/filewordcount
INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local2050700100_0001
INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local2050700100_0001_m_000000_0
INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@15b734b
INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: file:/home/hduser/Scrivania/input/sample.txt:0+530
INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local2050700100_0001_m_000001_0
INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@62d1f025
INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: file:/home/hduser/Scrivania/input/matrix.txt:0+255
INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local2050700100_0001_m_000002_0
INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@3d04562f
INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: file:/home/hduser/Scrivania/input/matrix.txt~:0+235
INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local2050700100_0001_m_000003_0
INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@133d9211
INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: file:/home/hduser/Scrivania/input/sample.txt~:0+0
INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete.
WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local2050700100_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Application.<init>(Application.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.PipesMapRunner.run(PipesMapRunner.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local2050700100_0001
INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0
INFO mapred.JobClient: Job Failed: NA
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1357)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.runJob(Submitter.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.run(Submitter.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.main(Submitter.java:494)
```

I have tried with the Hadoop version:

- 0.19.2
- 1.2.1
- 2.2.0